# CSS - 3 divs float

Tags: html, css

I have a `div` container:

```
div {
   width: 100%;
   height: 300px;
   display: inline-block;
}
```

In this div I want to align 3 images like this:

```
-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-   -.-.-.-.-.-.-.-
|             |   |             |
|             |   |      2      |
|             |   -.-.-.-.-.-.-.-
|      1      |   -.-.-.-.-.-.-.-
|             |   |             |
|             |   |      3      |
-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-   -.-.-.-.-.-.-.-
```

I use for this:

```
.photo-grid-3 .photo-grid-item:nth-child(1) {
    width: calc(50% - 5px);
    height: 250px; float: left;
}

.photo-grid-3 .photo-grid-item:nth-child(2) {
    width: 50%;
    height: 120px;
    margin: 0 0 5px 5px; float: left;
}

.photo-grid-3 .photo-grid-item:nth-child(2) {
    width: 50%;
    height: 125px;
    margin: 0 0 0 5px; 
}
```

But everything I get is:

```
-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-   -.-.-.-.-.-.-.-
|             |   |             |
|             |   |      2      |
|             |   -.-.-.-.-.-.-.-
|      1      |  
|             |                
|             |               
-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-
```

There is no 3th div.

Comment: Maybe it's the third selector? I assume you have the divs inside this div without other markup. There it also says nth-child(2) instead of nth-child(3).

Comment: Also to float a div you need to make it absolute positioned and parent relative positioned.

Comment: If that's ok then check the 3rd div you are not assigning any floats too. try checking it under the 1st one. `display: hidden` 1st one and check

Comment: @Fuzzzzel Oh, such a simple resolution... Just by mistake :) Thank you very much, please answer to this topic without commenting

Comment: @Ahmad no that's absolute positioning, not floating at all. You are taking the object out of the flow whereas floating is part of the document flow.

Comment: For HTML/CSS/JS problems providing a fiddle or snippet here, is really helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just had a typo in your CSS:

```css
div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.photo-grid-3 .photo-grid-item:nth-child(1) {
  width: calc(50% - 5px);
  height: 250px;
  float: left;
}

.photo-grid-3 .photo-grid-item:nth-child(2) {
  width: 50%;
  height: 120px;
  margin: 0 0 5px 5px;
  float: left;
}

.photo-grid-3 .photo-grid-item:nth-child(3) { /* here was the typo */
  width: 50%;
  height: 125px;
  margin: 0 0 0 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="photo-grid-3">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/" class="photo-grid-item">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/120/" class="photo-grid-item">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/125/" class="photo-grid-item">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Without box-sizing: border box your margins will always break your layout. And you first have to sort out the half width containers, then do the two 1/4 sized/stacked containers in the right hand half.

I leave it to you to sort how it will break down responsively, but this works:

```css
* {
box-sizing: border-box;
}

.one-half {
width: 50%;
float: left;
border: 1px solid red;
height: 200px;
}

.one-half-vertical {
height: 100px;
border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="one-half">
1
</div>
<div class="one-half">
<div class="one-half-vertical"></div>
<div class="one-half-vertical"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: he would have to use `clear` after 2nd vertical image in order to put an element below these images

Comment: No, he wouldn't, because they are both block elements and as such are self clearing. @HassanZia

Comment: didn't know about it :/ thnx anyways

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you to use flex layout:

```css
.main {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}
.blue {
  margin-right:5px;
  background: blue;
  flex: 1;
}
.sub {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.red {
  flex: 1;
  background: red;
  margin-bottom:5px;
}
.green {
  background: green;
  flex: 1;
  }
```

```html
<div class="main">
 <div class="blue"> Put Image One here</div>
  <div class="sub">
   <div class="red"> Image 2 here</div>
   <div class="green">Image 3 here</div>
 </div>
</div>
```